# Elasticsearch on Heroku: Invalid or missing build flavor [oss]

Tags: elasticsearch, heroku, jhipster

When I deploy my JHipster app (that uses Elasticsearch) to Heroku, it's unable to connect to the Bansai add-on. Error is:

```
... app[web.1]: Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: Invalid or missing build flavor [oss]
... app[web.1]: at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performClientRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:2084)
... app[web.1]: at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.internalPerformRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1732)
... app[web.1]: at org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient.performRequest(RestHighLevelClient.java:1717)
... app[web.1]: at org.elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient.exists(IndicesClient.java:963)
... app[web.1]: at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RestIndexTemplate.lambda$doExists$2(RestIndexTemplate.java:103)
... app[web.1]: at org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.ElasticsearchRestTemplate.execute(ElasticsearchRestTemplate.java:408)
```

It works fine when I run it locally in a Docker container.

Related JHipster issue: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/18650

I'd love to find a fix.

Comment: Hi Matt, does this help? https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/76091